# Вызов Activity из списка ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, io, android-resources

Всем привет. У меня возник вопрос. Как вызвать `Activity` через нажатие на одном из вариантов из списка `ListView`, и чтобы на втором `Activity` показало текст из папки `res/raw`. 
В одной статье было написано, что можно делать таким образом:

```
private String Iv_ar[]={ 
"1. Text1",//n0 
"2. Text2",//n1 
"3. Text3",//n2 
"4. Text4" //n7 
};
```

Но там не было полного кода и вообще объяснения.
Потом в папке `res/raw`. Создать файлы в формате `.txt` или `.html`. С названиями n0.txt, n1.txt, n2.txt, n7.txt. При нажатие на одном из вариантов, открывается текст из этих файлов.

Подскажите как такое реализовать? Желателен ответ с пояснениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос очень общий и объемный, но примерно это будет выглядеть так:

1. Добавляете обработчик кликов для `ListView`, получаете в нем позицию, запаковываете ее в интенет и запускаете новую активити:

   ```
   mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("POSITION_KEY", position);
           startActivity(intent);
   });
   ```
2. Во второй активити получаете позицию:

   ```
   int position;
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   if (intent != null) {
       position = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION_KEY", -1);
   }
   ```
3. В зависимости от позиции читаете нужный файл:

   ```
       String content;
       switch (position) {
           case 1:
               content = loadStringFromRawResource(getResources(), R.raw.file_1);
               break;
           case 2:
               content = loadStringFromRawResource(getResources(), R.raw.file_2);
               break;
           case 3:
               content = loadStringFromRawResource(getResources(), R.raw.file_3);
               break;
           default:
               content = "Empty content";
               break;
       }
   ```

Код методов для чтения:

```
private static String loadStringFromRawResource(Resources resources, int resId) {
    InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(resId);
    String content = streamToString(inputStream);
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}

private static String streamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    String line;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь. Я еще новичок в этой сфере. А все эти коды куда вводить?

Comment: @akmaltilloev, Первый – в `onCreate` активити, в которой находится `ListView`. Второй и третий – во вторую активити. Методы для чтения можно выделить в утилитный класс.