# Вызов текста из папки res/raw из списка ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-resources

Посмотрел [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699741/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-activity-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-listview) как вызывать текст из папки `res/raw` при нажатии на элементы `ListView`. Но при нажатии на них у меня выходит только `layout/activity_main2.xml`, а текст из папки не отображается. Мне кажется куда-то не туда код вставил. Помогите, пожалуйста.

MainActivity.java:

```java
package ru.testlistview.test_listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list_view;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.chemical_elements, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("POSITION_KEY", position);
                startActivity(intent);
                };

    });
    }

}
```

MainActivity2.java:

```java
package ru.testlistview.test_listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        int position;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            position = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION_KEY", -1);
            String content;
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    content = loadStringFromRawResource(getResources(), R.raw.hydrogenium);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    content = loadStringFromRawResource(getResources(), R.raw.helium);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    content = loadStringFromRawResource(getResources(), R.raw.lithium);
                    break;
                default:
                    content = "Empty content";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

        private static String loadStringFromRawResource(Resources resources, int resId) {
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(resId);
            String content = streamToString(inputStream);
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return content;
        }

        private static String streamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.testlistview.test_listview.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list_view">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

В activity_main2.xml ничего не добавлял

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.testlistview.test_listview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Вы прочитали ресурс в переменную `content` и ничего с ней не делаете. Что бы увидеть текст нужно вставить его в `TextView`, например.

Comment: @Real, как правильно вставить текст, чтобы всё работало? Я пытаюсь в TextView вставить переменную content, но у меня пишет, что пустое Activity.